# How to build debug dynamic libraries?

Tags: build, cmake, dynamic-linking, poco-libraries

I am building the Poco libraries from source code using `cmake`, following the instructions from the official website, on OSX High Sierra.

From that I get a bunch of files representing the dynamic libraries with extension `*.dylib` for example `libPocoJSON.23.dylib`.

However an external application is looking (in the same path locations), apart from the files created with the build, for other files of the library with a similar name such as to the created ones (they are different only for a `d` appended to the first part of the name). One example of such file is:

```
libPocoJSONd.23.dylib
```

I have found that these files are created with the **debug build** (while the release build creates only the files without the `d` extension).

How to perform the build of the debug? Should I look for a flag to active in any of the `cmake` file or it is a complete different source code?

Answer (score 0):

> How to perform the build of the debug?

Use `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`

See [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) for details.